# How to find enumerated index of numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take the following array:

```py
test_array = np.array(
    [[398, 349],[399, 349],[400, 349],[402, 348],[403 ,348],
    [405 ,348],[406 ,348],[407 ,348],[408, 347],[409, 347],
    [412, 347],[413, 347],[414, 347],[415 ,347],[416, 347],
    [417, 347],[418, 347],[419, 347],[420 ,347],[421 ,348],
    [422, 348],[423, 348],[424, 348],[425, 348],[426 ,348],
    [427 ,348],[428, 349],[429, 349],[430, 349],[431 ,349],
    [432, 350],[433, 350],[434, 350],[435, 351],[436, 351],
    [437, 351],[438, 352],[439 ,352],[440 ,353],[441 ,354],
    [442, 355],[443, 356]]
)
```

I need to find minimum value on the second column of `test_array` that is given by:

`minv=(test_array[np.argmin(test_array[:, 1])])`

Now, I want to find enumerated index of smallest of that minimum value `([408,347])`

`itemindex = np.where(test_array==minv)`

... which gives a tuple list but I want the enumerated index of smallest element.

When I enumerated array using:

```py
for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(test_array):
          print(x, y, value)
```

... the computed enumerated index is `(8,0)` and `(8,1)`. I need to find enumerated index (8). Is there any method to compute this index of smallest element in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index = np.argmin(test_array[:, 1])` is the index you need; you already have it, buried in a more complicated expression. You can then grab the value with `minv = test_aray[index, 1])`. No need for `where` or `enumerate`.